# How to write a class template to handle different data members?

Tags: c++

I would like to write a class template that behaves as follows:

- If I pass `Type_1` as an argument of the class instance, having then something like `TestClass<MessageType::Type_1> t1`, I want to see both memebers of the struct Message.
- If I pass `Type_2`, I want to see only the integer `member_2` and NOT the `member_1` inside the `Message` struct.

So, in a nutshell, I would like to decide the what are the members according to the template parameter.

```
#include <string>

enum class MessageType
{
    Type_1,
    Type_2
};

template <MessageType messageType>
class TestClass
{
public:
    struct Message
    {
        std::string member_1;
        int member_2{0};
    };     
};
```

I've tried to use conditional statements but I got compiler errors

Comment: Sounds like you're looking after `std::enable_if` or such.

Comment: Have you looked up `template` specialization?

Comment: what do you mean with "I want to see" ?

Answer (score 1):

Whether the following is viable in your case depends. If possible I would refactor to have two different types and then pick one via specialization of a separate template:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

enum class MessageType
{
    Type_1,
    Type_2
};

struct message1 { std::string member1; int member2; };
struct message2 { std::string member1; };

template <MessageType mt> struct select_type;
template <> struct select_type<MessageType::Type_1> { using type = message1; };
template <> struct select_type<MessageType::Type_2> { using type = message2; };


template <MessageType select>
struct TestClass
{
    using message_type = typename select_type<select>::type;
};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```